# Visual Studio Code C# build Error On Ubuntu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Last year I have successfully installed Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04 to develop with Python.

Yesterday I have installed ".NET Core for C# coding on Linux" so I can code C# with Visual Studio Code.

Workspace directory contents shown here: http://fortitudevolution.com/VisualStudioCode/images/Selection_999(3031).png

I am using this `task.json` file located `parentdirectory/.vscode/tasks.json`

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "clean",
            "command": "dotnet clean",
            "type": "shell",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet build",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": "clean",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "clean release",
            "command": "dotnet clean --configuration Release",
            "type": "shell",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet publish --configuration Release",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": "clean release",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "runFunctionsHost",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": "build",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0"
            },
            "command": "func host start",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$func-watch"
        }
    ]
}
```

For the application code `Program.cs` shown in directory contents, I am getting this error when I run "Terminal -> Run Build Task":

> Executing task in folder C#: dotnet clean
>
> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+57a23d249 for .NET Copyright
> (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
>
> The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'dotnet clean'" terminated with
> exit code: 1.
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I would appreciate any help in resolving this.

Comment: _The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file_ - is there a project or solution in the current working directory? If not, switch directory to the one that contains your project file.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two very different applications and you should generally only tag the one that is being used.

Comment: Please, show your directory contents

Comment: I just updated my question with some more details.

Comment: I just changed the directory structure of my Workspace to this: http://fortitudevolution.com/VisualStudioCode/images/Selection_999(3034).png and now the build succeeded. But now when I try to run the "Program.cs" (hello world) app I get a pop up window with error "You don't have an extension for devugging C#. Should we find a C# extension in the Marketplace?" I already have installed "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp). Microsoft" as shown here http://fortitudevolution.com/VisualStudioCode/images/Selection_999(3035).png

Comment: Don't edit your question to change the topic entirely. If you have a different question, **ask it as a different question**.

Answer (score 1):

For each `command` in the `tasks` array, add `${workspaceFolder}`. So the first command for `dotnet clean` becomes `dotnet clean ${workspaceFolder}` and so on. This tells the `dotnet` command what directory to work from.

Comment: Thank you @Matt U I just changed the directory structure of my workspace to this: fortitudevolution.com/VisualStudioCode/images/Selection_999(3034).png and now the build succeeded.